# Passing parameters with dropdown on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I'm trying list data according with data choose on a drop down menu.

My service list data with a hardcode (id 6).

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:3854/listarServicosByEstab/' + '6'; // Hardcode!
```

How do I pass the select item ID to the service?

[image: Dropdown]

Dropdown HTML (ng-click doesnt work):

```
         <!-- Combobox -->            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="dropdown" ng-controller="EstabelecimentosPageCtrl">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_estabelecimentos" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Estabelecimentos
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_estabelecimentos" >
                    <li>
                        <a ng-repeat="estab in listaDeEstabelecimentos" href="#" ng-click="$parent.current = item">
                            {{estab.nomeEstab}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                Choose Test: {{item}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Menu Controller:

```
.controller('ListServicoCtrl', function($scope, $state, ListServicoService) {
ListServicoService.listarServicos().then(function(dados){
    $scope.listaDeServicos = dados;
});  });
```

Service:

```
.service('ListServicoService', function($http){

var url = 'http://localhost:3854/listarServicosByEstab/' + '6'; // Hardcode!

return{
  listarServicos : function (){
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
          return response.data;
        });
  }
}});
```

Comment: `ng-click="$parent.current = item"` what's `item` here?

Comment: That's was just a test to see if I can set the selected item to a var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="dropdown" ng-controller="EstabelecimentosPageCtrl">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_estabelecimentos" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Estabelecimentos
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_estabelecimentos" >
                    <li>
                        <a ng-repeat="estab in listaDeEstabelecimentos"   ng-click="passdata(estab.Id)">
                            {{estab.nomeEstab}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                Choose Test: {{item}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Your Controller**

```
.controller('ListServicoCtrl', function($scope, $state, ListServicoService) {

$scope.passdata = function(id){
ListServicoService.listarServicos(id).then(function(dados){
    $scope.listaDeServicos = dados;
});
} });
```

**Your Service**

```
.service('ListServicoService', function($http){



return{
  listarServicos : function (id){
      return $http.get('http://localhost:3854/listarServicosByEstab/' + id).then(function(response){
          return response.data;
        });
  }
}});
```

Remove href from anchor tag and make a function like I have shown in controller. By assuming that your json contains value like **Id** I have demonstrated it. Hope this code will work for you.

Comment: Almost there Mohammed! The id var is going to service as 'undefined' what make sense because on load the page I don't choose any option. But on ng-click nothing happens, are we missing something?

Comment: Got it! I changed the controller name and forgot it -_- your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: Just an observation, the list (its on tab under the dropdown) is not updating, I'll search for how to reload the tab when user change the option on dropdown.